# Failed to implement LoaderManager in class extended with Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, android-loadermanager

I am newbie in android and have used this code while when i am trying to open this Activity its giving me error.
   **CODE:**

```
public class LoginActivityService extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<User>>
{  Context context;
   EditText userName,password,version;
   Button logoutBtn;
   LoginLoader loginLoader;
   ImageButton loginBtn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_view_service);
    context = this;
    userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName1);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password1);
    loginBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.login1);
    logoutBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout1);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(userName.getText().length() == 0 || password.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"UserName Or Password Should be Filled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                userName.setText("");
                password.setText("");
            //HOW CAN I WRITE BELOW LINE INSIDE { } 
            }
        }
        });
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, (LoaderCallbacks<List<User>>) this);
    }
     @Override
        public Loader<List<User>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
         loginLoader = new LoginLoader(context,userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),"2013-07-10 01:18:26");
        /* args.putString("username",userName.getText().toString());
         args.putString("password",password.getText().toString());
         args.putString("apkStatusDate","2013-07-10 01:18:26");*/
            return loginLoader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<User>> arg0, List<User> proposals) {
        Log.i("User",""+proposals.size());
       }

    @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<User>> arg0) {}
}
```

WHILE on start if this activity i am getting error:

> 01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mrfs.android.surveyapp/com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.LoginActivityService}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.LoginActivityService cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.LoginActivityService cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.LoginActivityService.onCreate(LoginActivityService.java:54)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
>   01-23 02:05:32.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20375):    ... 11 more

Comment: At line 54 you have a cast problem just want to highlight that in case ActivityService.onCreate(LoginActivityService.java:54) 01-23

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 LoaderManager implementations in Android (one default and other in the support library). These are:

```
android.app.LoaderManager
android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager
```

If you included the wrong, it can cause the classcastexception.

Comment: i have these lines:      

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.R;

Comment: You should only have one of them.. v4.app.LoaderManager.

Comment: Yes, you should only use android.app.* OR android.support.v4.app*. If you include a mix of these when you use the LoaderManager won't work

Comment: now i have added import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;

Comment: First line of Your first comment: ... import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks... You should only import ONE kind of the implementations. (from the same package)

Comment: now i have imported this : import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.content.Context;                                         is it fine but getting error on initLoader line can somenoe please help me

Comment: Than you should change super class to FragmentActivity and than use getSupportLoaderManager() instead of getLoaderManager()

Comment: wait i am doing this and checking the result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45789/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-r4ng3lii)

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating your loader with:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
```

Your activity implements `LoaderCallbacks<List<User>>` so you just need to  pass 'this' as the parameter, no need for the cast.

Comment: so after following your suggestions i am getting error:       Multiple markers at this line
 - The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments 
  (int, null, LoginActivityService)

Comment: What's your min sdk version in the manifest? I do not get that compile error if I use import android.content.Loader;
import android.app.LoaderManager; with a minSdkVersion of at least 11.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: main problem is that i am extending class with Activity is it right or wrong.... and also getting error on getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);                      The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, 
 LoginActivityService)

Comment: I get that error if using the support library, but not if using the imports as per my last comment.

Comment: i have removed all errors can some one pls help me there is only one error The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, 
 LoginActivityService)     on the same line now remove List  and just using Single class

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the imports you are now using (I know you've been trying both the regular and support libraries and it's not clear which you now have in place)? I'll then take another look. Thx.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45798/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-nigelk)